# How to convert string key and IV to byte arrays for Rijndael

Tags: c#, .net, rijndael

The documentation says "If you use the following values, then you will get this result".

> **Block Size:** 128 
>   **Cipher Mode:** CBC 
>   **Padding Mode:** Zeros

**Key:** BTikvHBatPdAtgT3317QIQqGFY25WpIz

**IV:** a5Sg4U9m11Mw2tIZ

**Value to be encyrpted:** 2008-06-02 13:28:45,Statements,1234567,,06/01/2008,06/01/2008,0

And this how the encryption result should look like after all these values are used according the developer guides.

> b97f3985245be1065604c5808cebaa2e15813bf938cfaa3c198fd464565c13ced7c91ac6
>   b68326ce5ed5e81cb7de81acb9fcd1b1636127efbac3203da5bdccea

However, I cannot get this result for some reason, this is the code I used to populate this result but it gives me same characters at first and later on the characters changes as you may see in the result at very bottom of this question.

This is the code and below is the new output:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged();
  rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
  rij.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
  rij.Key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("BTikvHBatPdAtgT3317QIQqGFY25WpIz");
  rij.IV = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("a5Sg4U9m11Mw2tIZ");
  ICryptoTransform transform = rij.CreateEncryptor();

  byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("2008-06-02 13:28:45,Statements,1234567,,06/01/2008,06/01/2008,0");
  byte[] result = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
  Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(result));
}

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

My output :

> b97f3985245be1065604c5808cebaa2e15813bf938cfaa3c198fd464565c13ced7c91ac6b68326ce5ed5e81cb7de81ac

Note: I needed to update the question as I advanced and found a better solution but the new problem has arose right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were talking about weird characters in your output - actually, the output you posted is hex encoding, so you should try to encode yours to hex, too, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c).

Edit:

I figured it out now. You need to additionally `Close()` either the stream or the writer - in CBC mode, this is needed to finalize the padding on the last block, if it is omitted then the last block will not be output. Next problem is that if you do this, then you will still end up with a slightly different output than the one expected in your example. Here's why: if you decrypt your example ciphertext, you will get:

```
2008-06-02 13:28:45,Statements,1234567,,06/01/2007,06/01/2007,0
```

It differs from your plaintext in that there's a 2007 at the end where you have 2008. If you fix this and properly close the stream then you will finally receive exactly the same output as in the example.

Comment: The weird thing : "b97f3985245be1065604c5808cebaa2e15813bf938cfaa3c198fd464565c13ced7c91ac6b68326ce5ed5e81cb7de81ac" is what was produced. There are some bits missing.

Comment: @Braveyard Hmm, that's exactly 32 characters, which corresponds to 16 bytes of output which is exactly one block. This means the final block is missing. You did flush the Writer, so that shouldn't be it... Thinking ...:)

Comment: What does `array.Length` say?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code, with Ruby. The funny thing is that it's actually AES-256, and *not* 128. I assume that's because of the 32 bytes key instead of the required 16 bytes. You should get the same result as now if you set BlockSize to 256. But I can't see why there's any output missing, I get exactly the same result as you expected. Can't see what's wrong with your code right now.

Comment: If I change the BlockSize to 256, I receive this error "IV length is different than block size"

Comment: Weird. It's definitely AES-256. But OK, that's a different story. Why won't that last block appear in your case??

Comment: I wish I could know why. It just doesn't appear.

Comment: Does it help if you call `Close()` on the writer or the stream before you convert the stream to an array?

Comment: I tried `Close()` and now the result changed but still not true : b97f3985245be1065604c5808cebaa2e15813bf938cfaa3c198fd464565c13ced7c91ac6b68326ce5ed5e81cb7de81ac36b1106392bd8303d2aedf2c26161a8a

Answer (score 2):

This key and IV you have look like base64 encoding...

```
rij.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("BTikvHBatPdAtgT3317QIQqGFY25WpIz");
rij.IV = Convert.FromBase64String("a5Sg4U9m11Mw2tIZ");
```

Comment: It throws this error "IV length is different than block size."

Comment: Well, obviously they *are* of different length... which documentation are you referring to? Are you sure it's related to the .NET implementation of Rijndael?

Comment: The documentation for the IV property says this: "The size of the IV property must be the same as the BlockSize property.". So obviously the example you have can't work.

Comment: The documentation comes from a highly-regarded company which we are using to integrate our applications. So they need to be fine.

Comment: Although it looks like Base64, the IV string has the correct size (16 bytes). The key is too long, but this shouldn't hurt. So I assume the example really expects those two values...

Comment: @Braveyard, I'm not saying this documentation is not fine, but perhaps it's related to another implementation.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: When I use `FromBase64String()` method, it produces completely different string but if I use `encoding.GetBytes()` method it produces correct one with missing bytes.